# How to add sheets title in google spreadsheet API using java

Tags: google-sheets-api

I had created sheets in google spreadsheet but I want to update the title of created sheets of Spreadsheet. Example: I want to update the Sheet1 title to "Birthday".

Comment: You can try [updating](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#change_a_sheet_title_and_size) the title and other sheet properties by making a [updateSheetProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatespreadsheetpropertiesrequest) request in the [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) method.

Comment: Hi, Can you give demo of it because I didn't understand.